# Setting a variable name from an array

Tags: vba, coreldraw

I wonder if this is possible, basically I want to generate a set of variables (sh0, sh1, sh2 etc). I'm thinking of using an array, but I can't get to make it work.
Here's my code:

```
Dim intI As Integer
Dim shArray(0 To 10) As String
For intI = 0 To 10
    shArray(intI) = "sh" & intI
    Dim shArray(intI) As Shape 'stumped in this part
    Set shArray(intI) = s3.Duplicate(0, s3.SizeHeight * -1)
Next intI
```

Running a block of code above will generate a "Constant expression required" error. I know you cannot declare a variable that way, I just can't think of other method.
Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do with: `shArray(intI) = "sh" & intI
    Dim shArray(intI) As Shape 'stumped in this part`?

Comment: Declaring it as 'Shape' type. In the end it should be like Dim sh0 As Shape... etc.

Comment: @Ran_TH  what do you want to do with the array of shapes you want to create ? what is the relation between the array of shapes and `shArray(intI)` ?

Comment: May be you dont need the first two lines of the loop, just `Set shArray(intI)=...`, and you get an array of shapes? (and change the declaration to `Dim shArray(0 To 10) As Shape)`

Comment: @ShaiRado basically I want to create duplicates of shapes and I need to generate each shapes their own name.. so I'm trying to use array.

Comment: VBA is not VB6, just its retarded cousin that serves as an embedded macro scripting language.  Don't tag VBA questions as VB6.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I finally solved my problem so I thought I'm gonna answer my own question anyway as future reference

So instead of trying to use Array I'm using VB Collections instead, so my code in the end runs like this:

```
Dim sColl As New Collection
Dim shDupe As Shape
Dim i As Integer
Dim f As Shape
Set shDupe = ActiveSelection.Group
sColl.Add shDupe
For i = 1 To 3
    If sBottomLimit = 1 Then
        Set f = sColl(1)
        Set f = f.Duplicate(f.SizeWidth, 0)
    Else
        Set f = sColl(i)
        Set f = f.Duplicate(0, f.SizeHeight * -1)
    End If
    sColl.Add f
Next
```